# Overriding the css in Standard Components in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have a particular client. I want to provide completely different looks and feels to the users of that client in Community. I did this by,

Creating a custom theme layout
Creating branding sets
Page Variants
But, the problem is, for the standard component, I cannot change the look and feel to align with the theme. For example, I have a dark background page variant, so I need a standard list view that will align with the dark theme. A white background list view in a dark theme seems odd, right?

Can you give me any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Overrides](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm) for this. Also for specific requirement like CSS to Components like listViews, you can create your own custom component with your own css.